# How do I correctly size the height of a Telerik RadGrid when using a Master Page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid with 100% height in a RadPane of a RadSplitter that also has 100% height. If I have no Master Page the RadGrid automatically sizes to the height of the browser window without a problem. If I use a Master Page the height of the content of that Master Page is not included in the calculation and as a result the footer of the RadGrid is truncated. Can anyone suggest the best approach to solve this?

[image: Truncated RadGrid]

**Master Page**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, form 
        {
            height:100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;    
        }
    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:blue;">Test Master Content</div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
        </form>
</body>
```

**Child Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server" Width="100%" height="50px" BackColor="Red">
             <p>This is a test</p>
        </telerik:RadPane>
        <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadSplitBar1" runat="server" />
        <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
            <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="AjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
                <AjaxSettings>
                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                        <UpdatedControls>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                        </UpdatedControls>
                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                </AjaxSettings>
            </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" 
            runat="server" 
            Width="100%"
            Height="100%"
            OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" />
    </telerik:RadPane>
    </telerik:RadSplitter>
   </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re combining fixed heights with relative heights, the master body is 100% of the browser height but adds a 100px to that, sending it off screen.
In the content you have radpane 2 at 100% but Radpane1 is 50px …so again  its pushed offscreen – but you then have the radsplitter saying to only show 100% of the browser, hence the chop off
You need to play around with those values until you feel it looks acceptable, try setting radsplitter to 140%  …and welcome to css tweakville

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would expect that setting radpane1 height to 50px and radpane2 height to 100% would mean that radpane2 would use 100% of the available height which is the height of the browser window less the 50px. This appears to be the case as the page works perfectly without a master page. It's only when using a master page that the extra 100px fixed height is not accounted for. I'll play around with the radsplitter percentages but I was hoping there might be a more precise fix like extending the resizing JavaScript code to account for the extra 100px.